# Como contar quantas instâncias de um programa estão rodando a partir de uma pasta compartilhada?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, microsoft-access

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que roda a partir de uma pasta compartilhada. Na mesma pasta fica o banco de dados Access. Para evitar conflitos no Access, apenas será permitido que ele seja executado por apenas um usuário por vez, não sendo permitido que dois usuários de máquinas diferentes possam rodar a aplicação ao mesmo tempo.

Pensei em um método lusitano, criando um arquivo temporário a cada 5 min, contendo a data e hora atual. Onde, se outro usuário tentar executar a aplicação e este arquivo existir na pasta, não seja permitido o seu acesso. E, caso haja algum bug na execução da primeira instancia e o arquivo permaneça na pasta, caso este tenha sido criado há mais de 5 min, seja permitido um novo acesso.

Existe algum método mais 'elegante' para este tipo de controle?

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão que qualquer método será lusitano (ou pior que isso). O ideal seria fazer uma solução que não dependa disso.

Comment: Mas daí seria possível com o banco ms-access? Teria que migrar para o SqlServer?

Comment: Eu acho que não. O Access é uma solução para uso bem básico. Até o SQLite é melhor que o Access, embora nesse cenário ela vá ser potencialmente problemático também. è um caso que um servidor seria adequado.

Answer (score 1):

@Leandro não seria o caso de você abrir o Access em modo exclusivo? Se você estiver usando `OLE DB`, ajuste sua `Connection String` adicionando `Mode=12;`
Ficando algo do tipo

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\northwind.mdb;Mode=12;
```